# byte array with swedish char

Tags: arrays, utf-8, arduino, ascii

I have this function.

```
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i=0;i<length;i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();
  for (int i=0;i<length;i++) {
    Serial.print(payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

It is from the [PubSubClient](http://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/api.html#callback), the problem I have now is the output.

> Message arrived [topic] Ã¥ Ã¤ Ã¶
>   1951653219516432195182

Comment: Since *Arduino* simply prints the input data *verbatim* I would dare say that it doesn't look like an issue with *Arduino* but rather related with the tool/software you use to display data. Could you elaborate a bit more on how that works?

Comment: `Serial.print((char)payload[i]);` works for ASCII encoded character, which are only 1 byte wide. If you are using a different encoding (like, UTF8, UTF-16, UTF32 etc.), you can't print the string that way because one displayed character can be multiple bytes wide. What's the input character set? If you have any swedish special chars in it, chances are it's not ASCII. Have you tried to do a simple `String x = String((char*)payload); Serial.println(x);` (if `payload` is NULL-terminated)?

Comment: Another thing: If you interpret the number sequence (195,165,32,195,164,32,195,182) as a UTF8 string, you get "å ä ö".. does that make sense, is that the original input?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I can't follow the reasoning in your first comment. `payload` is an array of `bytes`, `Serial.print()` is just copying one `byte` from `payload` onto the output `Serial` channel. Both `char` and `byte` have `8-bit` width, so the cast does nothing in practice and the exact same input data should appear as output. So, how does the *Arduino* code have anything to do with the **interpretation** of `Serial` data? That should depend **solely** on the receiving side, and how they decide to *interpret* incoming values.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin right, so you would either have to use a serial program that decodes it in UTF8 (miniterm.py / screen maybe, because Arduino IDE does not support this as of http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/UTF-8) or use the in the last link mentioned code at http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/Utf8ascii.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt now that's a sensible suggestion, I think it could make a good answer too.